# Typescript: emit compile time warnings to avoid committing temporary changes

Tags: typescript, compiler-warnings, emit

I work in VSCode on an angular app.
Sometimes I add debug code that I need to remove before committing.
I want the temporary code to emit a warning in the Problems window where the ts-lint output usually shows.

In e.g. C++ I can do `#pragma message ("Warning goes here")`

What is the simplest way to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: You can use [console.log("Warning goes here")](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-console/)

Comment: @NikitaMadeev that's not a compile time warning, is it?

Comment: It already depends on the settings of your configuration, if `tslint` is involved in the build, then this will be a warning during compilation. Example https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader

Answer (score 1):

For TypeScript specifically, there's no convenient standard solution to this. You need some kind of linter or extra tool to enforce such checks.

One option that you might find interesting is [git-confirm](https://github.com/pimterry/git-confirm) (full disclosure: I wrote this). It's a git hook, which asks you to confirm before committing anything that matches a configurable set of patterns. It's not typescript specific, it'll work for any content at all where you're using git, and it can match whatever patterns you like.

For example, you can write your messages prefixed with `TODO:`, and if you try to commit any changes that add a line like that then it'll ask you to that confirm first, and cancel the commit for you if that's rejected. TODO is also convenient because that's lots of standard tools to highlight & list those for you.

A demo:

[image: Live demo, adding a TODO and showing the confirmation]